# Selecting from nested array

Tags: json, jq

Given this input

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "001",
      "metadata": {
        "item1": 1
      },
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "type": "type1"
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "type": "type2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "002",
      "metadata": {
        "item1": 1
      },
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "type": "type1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "003",
      "metadata": {},   
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "type": "type1"
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "type": "type2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to output this

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "Item1": 1,
    "Name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "Item1": 1,
    "Name": null
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "Item1": null,
    "Name": "name2"
  }
]
```

However using this

```
jq '[.data[] | {id, "Item1": .metadata.item1, "Name": .records[] | select(.type == "type2").name}]'
```

jq query I am getting this

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "Item1": 1,
    "Name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "Item1": null,
    "Name": "name2"
  }
]
```

How can I get the '002' id object to output as well? I have tried various if then else conditions statements but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite new to `jq` so this is probably not an optimal solution.

If you `map` the `select` onto the *records* array instead, the surrounding object is not removed. For example:

*parse.jq*

```
[
  .data[] | 
  {
    id    : .id,
    Item1 : .metadata.item1,
    Name  : .records | map(select(.type == "type2"))[0].name
  }
]
```

Run it like this:

```
jq -f parse.jq file.json
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "001",
    "Item1": 1,
    "Name": "type2"
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "Item1": 1,
    "Name": null
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "Item1": null,
    "Name": "type2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be because the 2nd nested array doesn't satisfy the condition

```
select(.type == "type2")
```

Comment: I understand this but how can I have something that doesn't satisfy this condition yet still return something from the parent object metadata.